# What are the possible causes for this exception " HTTP 500 Erreur Interne de Servlet"?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey

I am developing web services rest. I often have this exeception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Erreur Interne de Servlet
```

What are the possible causes for this exception? knowing that in the window 'Error log' I found this:

```
Project facet osgi.subsystem has not been defined. It is used in plugin com.ibm.ws.st.osgi.core.
Project facet osgi.fragment has not been defined. It is used in plugin com.ibm.ws.st.osgi.core.
Project facet osgi.bundle has not been defined. It is used in plugin com.ibm.ws.st.osgi.core.
Project facet osgi.app has not been defined. It is used in plugin com.ibm.ws.st.osgi.core.
Project facet com.ibm.etools.javaee.cdi has not been defined. It is used in plugin com.ibm.ws.st.jee.core.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd need to check the logs on the server you sent that request to.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a project facet is not being properly loaded, try uninstalling that facet and installing it again, similar to JPA bugs maybe. go to the project properties, project facets, then uncheck that facet apply and close, then check it again apply and close, tell me if that works.

Comment: It shows me 'Project facet cannot be deselected. It critical to the proper function of this project'

Comment: Try right click on the facet and then select unlock, it should let you after that

Comment: Thank's, the error of project facet is disappearing, but the exception 500 not yet.

Comment: You are welcome! Error 500 is always something in the compilation/running time, try debugging where you think the error could be bro, and if you have access to logs of the server project, check them out or let us see them we might be able to help you :)